# What is the use of eval function inside Javascript?

Tags: javascript

```
<html>
<body>
<script type="text/javascript">
document.write("<br />" + eval("2+2"));
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

This gives me output as 4.

If i remove the eval function and run the same thing know it gives me the same output that is 4

```
<html>
<body>
<script type="text/javascript">
document.write("<br />" + (2+2);
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`eval()` takes a string and evaluates it as if it wasn't one. `(2+2)` is not a string.

```
console.log (typeof (2+2)); // returns number

console.log (typeof "2+2"); // returns string
```

Answer (score 2):

Eval allows you to execute command stored in variable:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var cmd = "2+2";
document.write("<br />" + eval(cmd));
</script>
```

Comment: it does not necessarily need to be stored in a variable.

Comment: Agree, but wanted to illustrate benefit of eval()

Answer (score 1):

Your observation is pretty correct. `eval()` does nothing else than to `evaluate` Javascript code. Therefore the outcome is identical. However, the usage of `eval()` is pretty frowned upon. That is for security and performance reasons.

For instance, a Javascript engine (at least most of them) always trys to optimize your code in terms of access performance. Without going to deep here, accessing a pretty deep *scope chain* property is costly, so engines will optimize that access with *hash lookup tables*. By invoking `eval()` this mechanism can no longer be used and therefore, it's slower to lookup the property.

That is only one example why the usage of `eval()` is not recommendable, there are plenty more.

Answer (score 1):

`eval` tries to execute a **string** as if it were a script - in your example `(2+2)` is not a string so it has no effect.

Also, [`eval` is evil](http://javascript.crockford.com/code.html)...

Answer (score 1):

With 'eval', you can do things like this:

```
<html>
<body>
<script type="text/javascript">
    var command = prompt('input command');
    eval(command);
</script>
</body>
</html>
```